# How can I store the output of .filter in an array or string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I store the output of a filter() function in an array or string to later use in another function?

```
jQuery('.marca').change(function(){
  var regex = new RegExp(/^2x\d$/);

  if(jQuery(this).find('input').prop("checked")) {

    jQuery(this).nextAll().filter(function() {

// I would like to save the output from this .filter 
// function to use to make a string of classes to pass to the next function.
      console.log(this.className.match(regex)); //output below
      return this.className.match(regex);
  })    
    .show();
  } else {
    jQuery(this).nextAll().hide();
  }
});
```

I use the above code to check the classes of a form with checkboxes and display a "subclass" only if the previous button was checked.
I use regex and filter() to find and display the next set of classes and I want to pass the resulted classes in the next jQuery selector to avoid manually adding them.

Hope I'm making some sense. Here is a fiddle with the entire code for a better understanding - https://jsfiddle.net/srjjj/brtp8x2h/9/

I have tried to simply add the result in a variable, but it won't store the entire set of values but only the last one (.2x4).

Here is the above console.log output and I guess the reason it's not working is because this is not an array of arrays but 4 different arrays but I'm not sure what to do next and how to save all of them in a variable.

[console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbW0F.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried declaring an array outside of the filter function and then pushing values in that array?

```
var matched = [];
jQuery(this).nextAll().filter(function () {
    matched.push(yourFilteredElement);
});
```

Comment: I have tried to make it work using .push() as suggested. The problem is that "jQuery(this).nextAll().filter" is returning a huge list of objects and push() will make a huge array of arrays.

Comment: and it's not a single Object for all elements, it's creating an object for each iteration. Ex: If I use window.alert on the returned value, I'll receive x number of popups.

Comment: Your question: “how to store output of .filter() in an array”? If the array is too big, you need to filter better.

Comment: The filter is working fine for the code to run and only display what I want but the problem is that it's also returning a null object for all "filtered out" elements. https://imgur.com/PQqH70S

Comment: I have managed to make it work with push() but I also needed to filter out null values and join() them in a string. Thanks